# SOQL for attachment

Tags: soql

How i can access attachment id from this query..

```
List<Email__c> e=[SELECT email_body__c,(SELECT Id,Name FROM Attachments) FROM Email__C where id='a05i0000002R7iBAAS'];
for(email__c e1:e)
 {
        System.debug(e1.Attachments.id);
 }
```

Getting error.. Invalid foreign key relationship Email__c.Attachments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 List<Email__c> e=[SELECT email_body__c,(SELECT Id,Name FROM Attachments) FROM Email__Cwhere id='a05i0000002R7iBAAS'];
for(email__c e1:e) {
List<Attachment> attList = e1.Attachments;
System.debug('@@@@Attachment list'+attList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When traversing relationships incorrectly. Each relationship between objects ends in `__r` and you can verify their names in the Enterprise WSDL. Chances are though that it's `Attachments__r`, so your Apex likely should be:

```
for(email__c e1:e)
 {
      for(Attachment a:e1.Attachments__r)
      {
        System.debug(a.id);
      }
 }
```

Comment: if Email__c contains multiple attachments, the above case will fail,am i rite ?

Comment: You're right; I've updated my answer to show how to traverse the inner query.

Comment: rite, i given same solution but not traversing through attachments but displaying all the attachments in debug logs

Comment: Wouldn't you be traversing them to display them? What's your goal? You could also use the indexer, `e1.Attachments__r[0].id`, if you want a specific entry.